# Resolve GLM path in Windows 10 for CEGUI

Tags: c++, cmake, glm-math, cegui

I'm trying to set up my system for UI development with CEGUI (v 0.8.7). 
That failed on missing dependency GLM. Initially, I also got a deprecation warning for `CMP0045`.

- I then downloaded and built GLM from source (v 0.9.9.8). CMake gave me 190 projects for GLM (all of them test projects), cmake configure and generate succeeded. I built the projects. Apparently, all of them were test projects, so I assume GLM to be header-only.
- Re-run trying to cmake configure CEGUI failed again. 
  I then set the "missing environment variable" `GLM_H_PATH` manually. I tried the path where GLM's `findXyz.cmake` resides, the directory where the `*.hpp` files reside that CMake wants to include for CEGUI setup, and a `;` concatenation of both. All without success. With the include path in my system env vars, I've even tried rebooting Windows before trying again.
- Another thing I tried was to add `GLM_H_PATH` as the path to GLM headers manually to the CMake-gui list. It just vanished on re-run of Configure.
- Because I thought maybe the space in my user name and the fact that I'd downloaded both libs to my User directory causes issues, I explicitly created a spaceless path and retried with the same result.

Can anyone please point me into the right direction as to what those two want from me to work together peacefully?

Answer (score 0):

This morning I couldn't find the code base any more. So I downloaded a new one, this time definitely CEGUI v0.8.7.

CMake setup and C++ building worked just fine this time.

**The Python tests, however, are reproducibly failing because there's a space in the project path.**

---

I will not pursue this issue further as I can't reproduce the problem any more. For the next few months I will still keep it open in case anyone can tell me what probably went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to compile something, watch the compilation guide video

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/VaD-MQJLtWk)

environment variable **GLM_H_PATH**  points to the path `cegui\dependencies\include\glm`